# Weird ~3MB/s Synology upload rate limit?

Tags: nas, synology

I've got a brand new DS216j NAS. It is a budget NAS, I know, still, I was hoping to get more than 3MB/s upload rate. I can't find out what is the limiting factor, but somehow all my uploads are limited to around 3MB/s.

Any ideas on what could be the reason? Network is fast enough, I can copy at a much higher rate between two computers on my LAN. What's also weird: if I simultaneously upload to the NAS via FTP, web (File Manager) and Windows Explorer I have around 3MB/s at EACH.

Is there some kind of weird connection limit in place? I have checked, and my user (not being the default admin), has not set any limits/quotas.

Any other ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: I'd check the read speed on the source device. I have a 416j, and it easily exceeds 50MB/s for uploads to directly connected disks (max of about 45MB/s for disks in my usb3 connected enclosure). you are sure you are not using 802.11G networking at the source are you? is there any setting under "Group Speed Limit" as described here: https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/file_user_create ?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I'm sure that I haven't configured wi-fi at all. Also there are no group speed limits in place.

Comment: Download speed is around 11MB/s for big files. Also not very good, but at least a little bit better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy, after posting here I changed the cable ... 70MB/s upload speed now. I'm sorry for your time. Thank you anyways!

Comment: incorrect or damaged UTP cabling can have a massive affect on throughput. Glad you got it figured out. By all means accept your own answer if it is appropriate.